# Does the Magic Keyboard with Touch ID work like a regular keyboard with T2 chip Macbooks?

Tags: keyboard, touch-id

The Magic Keyboard with Touch ID requires Macbooks with Apple Silicon to exploit the Touch ID feature but does the keyboard work like a normal keyboard with an T2 chip Macbook? The idea is to buy it to use with an Intel Macbook and future proof it in case I purchase an Apple Silicon mac in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does the Magic Keyboard with Touch ID work like a regular keyboard with T2 chip Macbooks?

**Yes**.

The Magic Keyboard with Touch ID would work with an Intel Mac just like a regular Magic Keyboard. The Touch ID authentication functionality would remain unavailable on unsupported Macs.

You *may* need a recent version of macOS installed for the keyboard to be recognised and usable with your Intel Mac.

Answer (score 1):

The magic keyboard needs at least 11.3 (Big Sur). You have to configure the keyboard in Preferences and decide, whether you will use Function Keys directly or with fn-key.